# Fast copying between random addresses

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, x86-64

I'm developing an application which needs to perform a massive copying data byte-by-byte from one addresses to another addresses. Now'm using for loop in multithread. Size of arrays can be from 100k elements to 2M elements. It works relatively fast, but not enough. Is there a faster way to perform this task?

```
std::vector<uchar*> src, dst
//Filling src and dst vectors with pointers. src.size() and dst.size() are equal.

for (int i=0; i<src.size();i++)
   *dst[i]=*src[i]
```

**UPD:** It's an image processing task where pixel is 8-bit grayscale. Ready-to-use solutions such as OpenCV isn't suitable because it's even slower (up to 20 times). Maybe GPU solution is possible?

Comment: You could try [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with a parallel execution policy.

Comment: use `std::copy` or `memcpy` which are likely to be vectorised (though with optimisation enabled most compilers should vectorise your code as is)

Comment: Please don't tag c in c++ questions

Comment: Sometimes there are algorithmic improvements possible; some such might forgo copy of the vectors, maybe by coping references instead, but exploring that would require a higher level look at the problem.

Comment: memcpy suitable for linear copying, but in my case adresses can be in random order. Also, I tried to use OpenMP with #pragma parallel for, but it make things slower.

Comment: When there is massive copying, to me, that usually means that things can be rearchitected. That is, why not just pass around pointers/descriptors? Maybe you could edit your question and explain the use case in more detail. Note that it sounds like you're memory bound, so a single thread can saturate the memory bus.

Comment: The whole idea of having vector of pointers each to one individual uchar feels quite wasteful.

Comment: Can you give an example of the addresses in the arrays? Can you also provide the size of the arrays. The performance will be *very dependent of the addresses* on modern (Intel) x86 processors (eg. if they are in the cache or not). The size of the array is important to know which optimization applies. Please add this in the question.

Comment: Okay, 8 bit greyscale image processing--got it. I've done a lot of that for professional/commercial applications, but raw _copying_ usually isn't necessary. If you were doing a transformation of some sort that couldn't be done in-place (e.g. rescaling), this might make sense, but that isn't just simple copying. So, please explain in more detail _exactly_ what processing you intend on doing.

Comment: The processing is similar to OpenCV's `remap()` (which also uses raw copying+interpolation, which I don't need). The "for loop algorithm with copying" makes a good result, the question only in execution speed.

Comment: "good result except for performance" is the whole point of people's comments here.  Why do you even have an array of pointers to individual bytes?  That's disastrously expensive for performance even if you have cache locality, since it means the copying has to happen 1 byte at a time.  And each byte copy requires 3 loads + a store: two 8-byte pointer loads, 1 byte-load, and one byte-store.  Compared to memcpy which can copy known-contiguous memory with one load + one store per *32 bytes*.  So it's usually limited by L2 or L3 cache bandwidth, not instruction decode/exec.

Comment: Of course your code has to read 2x 8-byte pointers per iteration, so that's also significant memory bandwidth, even if those loads do compete with a byte-load.  (And if the bytes are scattered around, that's disastrous for cache misses.)  Anyway, you almost certainly need to replace this loop by rewriting the code that uses it; there's not much if anything you can do to micro-optimize doing the exact same work on the same data structure more efficiently.  Even AVX-512 gather/scatter has a minimum element size of 4 bytes.

Comment: The only reason for 1-byte copying is that the addresses (both source and destination) can be in random order and I can't use a massive copying such as `memcpy()`, neighbor bytes at source are always not neighbors at destination. Is the SIMD instructions can be used to do such random copying? Or pointers arrays sorting could help?

Comment: OpenCV's `remap()` using the same byte-by-byte copying but with even more calculation overhead.

Comment: You really should go back one step and change whatever gave you this horrendous data structure. This must be the worst possible way of accessing pixels in an image, aside from maybe a linked list

Comment: There is no chance a discrete GPUs can be faster for such a task since they are optimized for accessing data in big (contiguous) blocks from memory and the input is too small (it would be slower to upload/down the arrays to/from the GPU). Shared memory can help for scatter/gather accesses but only in some very-specific cases and we have no information about addresses yet. GPUs like SIMD-friendly code and your code is not.

Comment: Is there any pattern to which pixels end up near others?  If so, take advantage of it instead of making an array of pointers.  Once you have these 2 arrays of pointers, you've already lost.  You need to optimize earlier in your program so this expensive step can use a different algorithm, like everyone's been telling you repeatedly.  If you have a nearest-neighbour scaling function, pass in the old/new dimensions so you can do some SIMD shuffling on the fly, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved entire project on GPU, using GLSL. Arrays are replaced with 2D samplers. Even low-end Intel UHD can handle high resolutions at high framerate.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm developing an application which needs to perform a massive copying data byte-by-byte

That's very unlikely.

The only reason to create a copy is that the data is being modified in some way (and different pieces of code can't just share the same data in a "read only" way); and if the data is being modified in some way then it's very likely that you can merge the modification into the copying.

Maybe you're doing the same changes to all pixels, and it can be (e.g.) a "read 16 pixels from source, modify 16 pixels, write 16 pixels to destination" loop (where the work involved in modifying the pixels happens in parallel with pre-fetching the next pixels into cache, etc).

Maybe you're only modifying some pixels, and can do (e.g.) a lazy `if( pointer_to_row[row] == NULL) { pointer_to_row[row] = create_copy_of_row(row); } modify_row(pointer_to_rows[row]);` to avoid copying all the rows of pixels you don't modify. Maybe you can create a shared memory mapping of the data and let the operating system's "copy on write" virtual memory management take care of the copying for you.

Maybe you can have some kind of journal of changes and leave the original data alone (where you might have an `int get_pixel(int x, int y ) { int temp = check_journal(x, y); if(temp != NOT_PRESENT) return temp; else return get_original_pixel_data(x, y); }`.

Maybe you can combine multiple techniques (e.g. a small journal for each row of pixels, with a lazy "if/when journal for row becomes full, create new row from old row and journal, and reset the journal to empty").

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Lazy copying actually already used, pointers arrays already contains only not-null pointers (about 60% of an overall pixels) and it helps a lot. Shared memory mapping sounds interesting, I'll try to check it out.

Comment: @BrainRoM: If you have one 8-byte pointer for 60% of the 1-byte pixels in an image, your cache footprint is now 8 * 0.6 = 4.8x the size of the original for the vector of pointers.  If you instead just stored a scale factor or a stride so you could increment a pointer in the right patters to get the pixels of the original image, you'd need a constant size per image, and have an efficient access pattern.  Or if you copied the pixels you wanted, you'd have just 0.6x the original size, and not need to touch the original.